# Vue.js components + Laravel right management

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm unsure how to procede with using Vue single file components alongside Laravel's right management plugins. In general I'm loading the components on different pages, however different actions in components require different rights available, and passing the available rights directly to component seems kind of unsafe. 
What would be the correct approach here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the blade template together with laravel gates engine to render your views, you could pack the component inside a `can` statement

```
@can('view-component', 'component-name')
  <custom-vue-component></custom-vue-component>
@endcan
```

Specific use regarding permission checking in blade can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#via-blade-templates), general authorization info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization) and info about the gates [here]https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#gates().

Comment: That would solve how to display whole components, however if I need specific actions within a component right based? like EDIT / DELETE / TRANSFER and etc...?